# Terms for process that is supposed to run continuously VS running until completion

Tags: computer-science, terminology

Are there general abstract computer science terms to denote:

- a process that is supposed to be continuously running (doesn't have an end)

and

- a process that is supposed to run until completion (has an end)

respectively?

Examples from the first class: a web server, OS daemon processes. I would put here also any interactive application in general (a game, a browser, a word processor), because that's something that would run forever unless given (the wrong) external input. But I wouldn't put here an interactive application that was programmed to end itself in a certain amount of time, because that would come to a "natural end" even without external input.

Examples from the second class: a script that scrapes some data from the internet and builds a dataset, a program that takes a screenshot of my desktop and saves it, a command line utility that encrypts a file, etc.

I'm looking for terms that would distinguish a process based on whether it will come to an end (without external input) or will end up in some infinite loop. But I'm looking for "practical" terms, that could be used in an everyday technical environment.

I could think of math-y terms like "Finite" and "Infinite" processes (not sure if such terms are used anywhere), but I doubt they would be picked up and used in everyday's jargon.

I can't picture somebody at work ever saying "Oh, today we have to run a couple of finite programs and we have to add monitoring to our infinite ones". (It's a pity, because these sentences seem very concise and unambiguous to me!)

From what I've heard and read and used, the term "Batch job" is often used to denote the second class that I described. But I wouldn't know of a widespread term do denote the opposite class.

Plus, the term "batch" is a bit overloaded, and based on the context and the field you are in, it might be "enriched" with additional meaning. For example, if your context is "processing data", you might use "batch" to denote the way in which data gets processed in blocks as opposed to one-by-one. In machine learning you might have a script that trains a model either in "batch mode" (processing data N rows at a time) or in "online mode" (processing data one row at a time). In that case it may become hard to denote the training process as a "Batch job" or a "Batch process", because this might create confusion on whether you want to say that your process will end or whether you are going over data in batches.

Another good candidate for denoting the "Finite" class could be "Task". "Task" conveys the meaning of "something that needs to be started and completed".

But then in practice you can find the term used also for "infinite" things, for example in VSCode's watch tasks. In that case the meaning of "task" gets broadened to "something that I can start on demand", and the focus on "completable" gets lost.

Finally, I like Kubernetes' approach of providing two simple single-word terms for the 2 classes: "Deployment" (for things that are supposed to run forever) and "Job" (for things that are supposed to be completed), but I feel that both "Deployment" and "Job" suffer even more than "Batch" from being overloaded.

For example, "deploy" is already confusing within the Kubernetes lingo itself, because it might be used as a verb for denoting "starting something". A lot of people might say "I deploy this job" or "I deploy this deployment". To someone new to Kubernetes, trying to understand the concept of a Kubernetes's "Deployment", hearing "deploy" and "job" in the same sentence might be confusing.

The term "job" instead might seem like it's the proper word to indicate something that runs to completion, judging by this [rather incomplete wikipedia page on "Job (computing)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_(computing)). But "job" in the UNIX sense doesn't carry that meaning. And I think that "job" in the UNIX sense is much more widespread than its abstract homonym ("job" in the field of computing).

---

Any terms that you would like to suggest?

Or terms that you use in your everyday life in a technical environment?

Have you every thought about this topic, and what were your conclusions?

Comment: Removed tag "procssing". [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts. See tag-wiki [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you, I didn't see the description!